# MS Access VBA: Combine 2 SQL statements with a LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access, combobox

Hi all and thanks in advance for your help!
I am trying to use a JOIN to combine a fitlered SQL statement with a table in order to populate a combobox (makes sense?)

Here is the main SQL query:

```
MainSQLquery = "SELECT QuotationID, QuoteDate, EmployeeID FROM TestTable1"
```

I want to write a statement to use this with another table like so:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeName
FROM MainSQLquery LEFT JOIN EmployeeTable
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

But I can't get it right. I get a "Syntax error in FROM clause" even with something as simple as:

```
ComboSQL = "SELECT EmployeeID FROM " & MainSQLQuery
Me.Combo2.RowSource = ComboSQL
```

Do you guys know any way to do this?

*******BACKGROUND**********

For those of you who wants to see the bigger picture, I have a subform showing a list of quotations and based on a dynamic SQL statement, it is filetered with a WHERE clause based on different inputs and it looks like this when displayed:

```
QuoteID   Quote date    Employee ID
1         10/13          1
2         10/13          2
3         10/13          2
4         09/18          1
5         08/10          2
6         07/16          3
7         06/27          3
```

On the main form, I have comboboxes that I use to filter this subform, which works perfectly. But I also need my comboboxes to be filtered the same way as the subform content and without having any duplicate (that's the only thing I can't do right now).

So far I use the same filtered SQL query for the subform and all the comboboxes, so instead of having a neat Employee combobox that looks like this (with the example above):

```
1
2
3
```

I get that instead (same as the subform):

```
1
2
2
1
2
3
3
```

My idea is to have a main SQL query for the subform, and another SQLquery based on the main one for the comboboxes, something like that:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeName
FROM MainSQLquery LEFT JOIN EmployeeTable
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

if I could get this working, the filter would still be built in the mainSQL and I could group the EmployeeID field without problem.

I guess it should be fairly simple, but I can't get it right, there is something I don't know about using an SAL as source of another.

(I wish I could post pictures or a database sample, but a paranoid guy got my previous post deleted because of that, so it will have to do with text only, sorry about that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a `JOIN` you should have an `ON` to let the database know how to relate the tables:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeName
FROM (
    SELECT QuotationID, QuoteDate, EmployeeID 
    FROM TestTable1
) AS MainSQLquery LEFT JOIN EmployeeTable
ON MainSQLquery.EmployeeID = EmployeeTable.ID
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

The `LEFT JOIN` gets all records from the table on the left of the join -- `MainSQLquery` -- and only the records from the right table -- `EmployeeTable` -- that match. If no matches are found in the right table, a NULL value is returned.

Given this example:

```
TestTable1
QuotationID |   QuoteDate   |   EmployeeID 
--------------------------------------------
1               10/1/2014       1
2               10/8/2014       2
3               10/5/2014       3
4               10/10/2014      1
5               10/20/2014      5

EmployeeTable
ID  |   EmployeeName
----------------------
1       Jeremy Smith
2       Pam Engles
3       Achim Flemmish
4       Sandra Hayes
```

This would be the result of the above query:

```
Result
EmployeeID  |   EmployeeName
--------------------------------
1               Jeremy Smith
2               Pam Engles
3               Achim Flemmish
5               NULL
```

Comment: Hi jwatts. It works with the SELECT/FROM statements, but if I add a WHERE in the mainSQLquery, I get the "syntax error in FROM clause". Is there something else to add in this case?

Comment: I take this back, it works !! I just re-wrote it and for some reason the error didn't show up, unfortunately I have no idea what is the difference with my previous code! Anyway, thanks a LOT !!!